# Conditional Branching Issues

Tags: ruby, string, if-statement

Here is the code:

```
def main_menu
    print_main_menu
    user_selected  = gets.chomp
    if user_selected.downcase == "no"
        main_menu
    elsif user_selected == "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7"
        user_selected = user_selected.to_i
        call_option(user_selected)
    else
        main_menu
    end
end
```

This code uses calls to allow a user to make a selection from a main menu. Depending on the input, be it a certain number, a certain word, or something else, the respective method is called (in the case of a valid input) or the main menu is printed again (in the case of an invalid input or "no").

My questions are twofold.

1. Is there an efficient way to get rid of the literal string error that appears as a result of this redundant or statement on the `elsif` line? (the code itself works fine, but this error appears and is frustrating).
2. When an alternate/unspecified input is made by the user, the else branch doesn't execute and main_method doesn't start over. I have no idea why this is happening. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It won't generate an error because a string like `"1"` has a truth value. So those will always be true (since they aren't `nil` or zero).

Comment: I don't see the point of `if user_selected.downcase == "no"`.  Why not just delete that line and the one following, and change `elsif user_selected...` to `if user_selected...` (and then fix that line).  You should also check the logic to make sure this is doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elsif` line is not semantically valid relative to your intentions. In Ruby, you can't check a variables value against several other values via `x == v1 || v2 || ...`. You might want to consider using a [Ruby `case` statement](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/).

```
def main_menu
  print_main_menu
  user_selected  = gets.chomp

  case user_selected.downcase
  when "no"
    main_menu
  when "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
    user_selected = user_selected.to_i
    call_option(user_selected)
  else
    main_menu
  end
end
```

It should be noted that the following expression won't do what you think it should:

```
elsif user_selected == "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7"
```

This *will not* compare `user_selected` with each of the items separated by the logical OR.

The expression you are using, although not having the intent you are wanting, will not generate an error since this is a valid Ruby expression:

```
exp-1 || exp-2 || exp-3 || ... || exp-N
```

Which has the value of the first `exp-i` which is "truthy". That is, the first expression which doesn't evaluate to either `false` or `nil`.

So in this case, it represents a logical check of the Ruby expression:

```
(user_selected == "1") || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7"
```

The result of this expression will, as described above, be the first subexpression which is "truthy". If `user_selected` has the value "1", then the result will be `true` and the `elsif` will succeed. If the `user_selected` is not "1", then the value of the expression above will be `"2"` since it is "truthy", and the `elsif` will still succeed. In fact, it will *always* succeed (since `"2"` is always "truthy").

So your code will appear to work unless you enter something like `9` in which case the code will attempt to execute `call_option(9)` and perhaps generate some unexpected result depending upon what `call_option` does with unexpected argument values.

Comment: It's not invalid syntax, it's completely valid syntax. It's just not doing what he thinks it's doing.

Comment: @meagar what is it doing in actuality?

Comment: @zack I explain what it's doing in my updated answer. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: It's doing `(user_selected == "1") || "2" || "3" || ...`. If `user_selected == 1`, is true, you get `true`; If it's false, you get `"2"` every time. Note that I mean `"2"` and not `true`, your answer still isn't technically correct. The result is *truthy*, not `true`.

Comment: @meaguer indeed, when I used the word "true" I didn't mean literally (or I would have written it `true` rather than "true"). I'll reword the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use case:

```
case user_selected
when "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
    user_selected = user_selected.to_i
    call_option(user_selected)
else # includes "no"
    main_menu
end
```